# Single pixel on site and subdomain screwing up analytics

Tags: facebook-analytics

I've got my main website and then my e-commerce shop on a subdomain -- an entirely different Wordpress installation because I like to keep my shop and main site separate for security reasons. I've had the same Facebook pixel installed on both, but now with the advent of Facebook Analytics, all of my analytics are mixed together and it's a mess. Because I get high traffic to my blog and much lower traffic to my store, it's saying my conversions are like .003% when my store is actually converting closer to 4%.

So at this point I'm wondering, do I need different pixels on each site? What's the best way to go about this so that my Facebook Analytics aren't all screwy?

Answer (score 2):

I see two options for you at this juncture.

- The first, as you note, is to instrument separate pixels for each site. You then still have the option of viewing the data aggregated across each Pixel by creating an [Event Source Group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/omni-channel-analytics).
- The alternative would be to continue to log traffic on both sites with the same pixel, but to leverage the power of [Segments](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1012300315565213) so as to only view data from one site at a time. For example, you might create a segment like "Web Parameters: Current Domain is mystore.net"

The latter option will be easier in that it won't require you to instrument new logging on your sites, but the former is probably a better long-term option that will better leverage the paradigm of Facebook Analytics.

Comment: Nicely explained